# New Google Chrome compose with Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi all i have an issue with new gmail compose method. i had developed an extension which used to add users signature into body of gmail compose module. I was able to achieve this by inserting a script into the frames by using

```
`chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    activeTabs[0].id, { file: 'ExtractGmail.js', allFrames: true });
                  });`
```

and within the ExtractGmail.js script i used to call the body field simply using document dom. This was working and i was able to achieve my task but now as gmail have changed there compose feature now if i try to get the body element i get the element as undefined although i am clear that i am using the same id as is present in html. i have also tried getting the element through tag name and class name but still was not able to get any element back. As you can see i have to get the element to insert the signature into the body. Please can any one help me on this